# Is it possible to make user profile changes with AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-cognito, expo, aws-amplify

AWS Amplify can now be used with react native and expo SDK25 (Create React Native App) without ejecting first.  This is great for those looking to stay within the AWS ecosystem and use Cognito User Pools.

But I couldn't find a way to use AWS Amplify to let the user make updates to their data (e.g. fix a name spelling, change phone number, etc.).  Has anyone else been able to do this and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mutable user attributes are planned to be pushed in our next release this coming Monday 1/29/2018